# How to write a generic .htaccess file rule, regarding RewriteBase

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following rule in my `.htaccess` works just fine for routing calls to `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

However, this does **not** work when running on a temporary URL like `http://example.com/~test/`.

In such a case, the .htaccess file needs to read:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Note the extra `RewriteBase`.

Question: is it possible to write a rule in .htaccess to "detect" whether to apply that `RewriteBase`?

The reason is the .htaccess if version controlled, and I'd like for it to work on multiple installations.

Comment: I've spent so long screwing around with this, and have found the same problem. Why the hell cant RewriteBase have the same value as Alias? It's crazy...

Comment: Yes, it seems like a pain that's just "one of those things".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no reliable way to detect what the `RewriteBase` should be.  If there were, there would be no need for [the kluge that `RewriteBase` is](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), as mod_rewrite could just detect the correct base automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Trying the same and on my search I found that symfony2 frameworks `.htaccess` file is doing that at least it is stated in the file that it would. I tried to use it in my own setup but didn't work. Maybe that will help you guys somehow.

```
# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
# project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
# resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
# work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
# the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since version 2.4.16 `RewriteBase` directive is not required when the request is mapped via `Alias`.

Basically it means that if you have multiple `Alias`

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
Alias /siteA /var/www/docroot
Alias /siteB /var/www/docroot
```

**Before** 2.4.16 you need to specify the RewriteBase with some gimmick in `.htaccess` or use the Symphony way as suggested by @FitzPatrick.

**Since** 2.4.16 you don't need to touch your `.htaccess` and you don't get any `AH00128: File does not exist: errors anymore`.

Worth noting that CentOS 7.x comes with Apache 2.4.6 with security patches: as for 2022/01/07 you get 2.4.6-97.2 that fixes CVE-2021-40438. So if you want to manage multiple alias you need to upgrade with a different package, but this is another story...

Answer (score 1):

> ...does not work when running on a temporary URL like `http://example.com/~test/`

The "problem" in this instance really stems from using (what appears to be) an "[Apache per-user web directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html)". If `/~test` was a physical subdirectory then you would not need to explicitly set the `RewriteBase`, as the *directory-preifx* (the absolute filesystem path to the location of the `.htaccess` file) would be "correct". The issue here is that `/~test` does not relate directly to a physical subdirectory - it is a URL-path (as opposed to a filesystem path) and is essentially an *alias* to another part of the filesystem - and therefore is different to the directory-prefix.

By default, a relative *substituion* string in the `RewriteRule` directive is relative to the *filesystem* (the directory-prefix). But when using an Apache per-user web directory or `Alias`, it now needs to be relative to the URL-path. This is when the `RewriteBase` directive is required<sup>***1**</sup> - it enables relative substitution strings to be relative to the stated root-relative URL-path (as opposed to the default absolute filesystem path).

<sup>***1**</sup> Or, this can be calculated using a method as mentioned in @FitzPatrick's answer. This sets an environment variable that must be explicitly used in each *substitution* string as required. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

But note that this does not behave quite the same as when using `RewriteBase`. When using `RewriteBase`, the URL-path is only prefixed at the very end of the rewriting process. This can be an important factor if you have rules that are expected to chain together. (And this also behaves differently to when no URL-path prefix is specified at all.)

*Aside:* "Temporary" per-user web directories can cause other issues with root-relative URLs in client-side development. Unless these are factored into account on the development server then root-relative URLs are going to be different between servers.